# Average pizza orders for specific pizza place per day - SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, average

How could I determine the average orders per day for a specific pizza place using SQLite?

Table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE pizzaorders (
     id STRING PRIMARY KEY,
     pizza_place STRING,
     created_utc STRING,
);
```

I managed to GROUP BY number of pizzaorders per day for pizza place 'Dominos' like this (btw, the created_utc attribute is stored in UTC epoch-format):

```
SELECT 
   strftime('%d-%m-%Y', created_utc, 'unixepoch') AS dt, 
   COUNT(*) AS orders 
FROM pizzaorders WHERE pizza_place = 'dominos' 
   GROUP BY dt;

26-10-2017|543
24-10-2017|581
18-10-2017|593
30-10-2017|608
31-10-2017|621
25-10-2017|647
```

But how do I use the `AVG()` to get the average order per day for the specific pizza place (e.g. dominos in this example)?

Comment: can you share the result you're expecting?

Comment: @Mureinik Well, in the example above I'm expecting the average of all the orders i.e. 543 + 581 + 593 + 608 + 621 + 647 / 6 = ~598 - so to summarize: Dominos get about 598 orders per day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could divide the total count by the distinct number of days:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) /
       COUNT(DISTINCT STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y', created_utc, 'unixepoch'))
FROM   pizzaorders
WHERE  pizza_place = 'dominos'
```

Comment: By removing the 'DATE()' encapsuling it worked! So SELECT COUNT(*) /
       COUNT(DISTINCT STRFTIME('%d-%m-%Y', created_utc, 'unixepoch'))
FROM   pizzaorders
WHERE  pizza_place = 'dominos'

Comment: @Jesper I started answering for [tag:mysql] and noticed it was [tag:sqlite] mid-typing. The `date` is a remainder I should have removed and must have missed it, my apology. Edited and fixed, thanks for pointing it out.